# use a major mode from the internet

Tags: major-mode

After installing emacs on windows 10 and gone through the tutorial and downloaded a major mode [mt4.el](https://gist.github.com/RyanKung/6e95257a40f53d249c4a4d280eef8132) , 
Now where to save it and how to use it in emacs?

googling did not help me.

Comment: You will need to place this short gist of a major-mode in your .emacs path. and then 'require it in your config. read all about it in [major-modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Major-Modes.html). you can run try out and evaluate  this short code in the scratch buffer before.

Answer (score 0):

Find the package-user-dir with `F1 v package-user-dir` or `M-x describe-variable <RET> package-user-dir`.
Create the folder `mt4-mode` in the given package-user-dir.
Put a copy of the mt4.el file in that folder and edit the mql-compiler command to be correct for Windows (i.e., without wine.)
Run the mode with `M-x mt4-mode` or by `C-x C-f example.mt4` or `M-x find-file example.mt4`.

Comment: After following your instructions, now the compiler command looks like this `(defvar mql-compiler
"/Users/myName/Applications/Wineskin/MetaTrader 4.app/drive_c/Program Files/BTC-e Exchange MT4/metaeditor.exe'")` but I could not locate the file metaeditor.exe in my windows 10, in emacs `M-x mt4-mode` gives [No Match], any suggestions?

Comment: Found it and updated the command to the location for no avail.  `(defvar mql-compiler "C:\Program Files (x86)\Broker name\metaeditor.exe")

Comment: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_installing_packages.html